# Matrix Inverse and Linear Dependence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am reading a book and am on the section about matrix inverses and linear dependence.  I don't get what the author means by Cs = 0.  If C1 = C2 = 0, then wouldn't the Cs have to be 0 for the equality to hold?    If you do element wise multiplication and you multiply a vector by 0, well the result has to be 0.  So what's the point of this?  I can't think of any other value that C can take on so that Cs = 0.

[image]

He gives this example:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suppose a clearer way of putting it would be to say that $a_1, \dots, a_k$ are linearly independent if the equation $c_1a_1 + \cdots +c_ka_k = 0$ has *only the solution* $c_1 = 0,\dots, c_k=0.$ Think about an example where this is not the case. The equation for the columns of the matrix 
$$B = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}1 & 2 \\ 3 & 6 \end{array} \right]$$ 
is given by 
$$c_1 \left[\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 3 \end{array} \right] + c_2 \left[\begin{array}{c} 2 \\ 6 \end{array} \right] = \left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \end{array} \right],$$ 
which has (for example) the solution $c_1 = -2, c_2 = 1.$ Therefore, the columns of our matrix $B$ are linearly dependent, and the inverse of $B$ does not exist. In the example above, for the matrix $A$, the *only* solution was $c_1 = c_2 = 0,$ showing that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, and $A$ is therefore invertible.